# stopping a block enumeration fo a NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How do I stop an enumeration here if I am doing the following? I think the docs said that to set stop = TRUE. but when I do that inside the block it says that it isn't unassignable.

```
 [self.visibleViewControllers_ enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(visibleRect, viewRect)) {
               //break here
            }
        }];
```

Comment: stop is a pointer. You don't set stop to true because it is a pointer. You write *stop = YES

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Set `*stop` to `YES`

```
[self.visibleViewControllers_ enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(visibleRect, viewRect)) {
               *stop =YES;
               return;
            }
        }];
```

Comment: You probably also want a `return` statement immediately after setting `*stop = YES`, if there's anything later in your block.

Answer (score 2):

For SWIFT 2:

```
Dict.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock { (key, value, stop) -> Void in

            if(//Something){
                 //Do Something
            }
            else {
                //To Stop
                stop.memory = true
            }
        }
```